# How to cut a json with python

Tags: python, json

My plan is to "clean" the json below (json n.1) in order to only keep the location value, the date and the PM25 value (json n.2). I would like to do this with Python language. Does anyone know how to do this ? Many thanks for your support.

json n.1 (dict):

```
 'level': 'hyper-local',
 'date': '2020-12-14T15:00:00+00:00',
 'pollutants': {'NO2': {'description': 'Nitrogen dioxide',
   'concentration': {'mugm3': {'value': 22}},
   'aqi': {'elichens': {'value': 11.0,
     'category': 'Very Low Pollution',
     'color': '#6cef00'}}},
  'O3': {'description': 'Ozone',
   'concentration': {'mugm3': {'value': 27}},
   'aqi': {'elichens': {'value': 11.0,
     'category': 'Very Low Pollution',
     'color': '#6cef00'}}},
  'PM25': {'description': 'Fine particulate matter (< 2.5 µm)',
   'concentration': {'mugm3': {'value': 9}},
   'aqi': {'elichens': {'value': 15.0,
     'category': 'Very Low Pollution',
     'color': '#93f400'}}},
  'PM10': {'description': 'Fine particulate matter (< 10 µm)',
   'concentration': {'mugm3': {'value': 15}},
   'aqi': {'elichens': {'value': 15.0,
     'category': 'Very Low Pollution',
     'color': '#93f400'}}}},
 'global_aqi': {'elichens': {'value': 15.0,
   'dominant': 'PM25',
   'info': 'eLichens Air Quality Index (eAQI)',
   'category': 'Very Low Pollution',
   'color': '#93f400'}}}
```

My goal is to get something like this :

json n.2 (dict):

```
 'pollutants': {'PM25': {'concentration': {'mugm3': {'value': 9}}}}}}
```

I managed to extract the information I needed like this :

```
pprint(data)
data1=data['location']['latitude']
data2=data['location']['longitude']
data2=data['date']
data3=data['pollutants']['PM25']['aqi']
```

Output for data1 : 5.7782350000000005 (float)
Output for data2 : 45.204480000000004 (float)
Output for data3 : '2020-12-14T15:00:00+00:00' (string)
Output for data4 : 15.0 (float)

Now I am trying to merge data1, data2, data3 and data4 in a json file

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Show us the code and describe the problems you encounter, don't ask for a full solution.

Comment: Just JSON.loads() it, and then you can filter the required components and then do a JSON.dumps().

Comment: Hi @Mike, I updated my question.

Comment: Thanks @Han, I am trying to use your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed extracting the data I needed with this piece of code (d is my json n.1, which is a dict).  I guess this is not the perfect solution, but it works :)

```
location,date,pm=d['location'],d['date'],d['pollutants']['PM25']['aqi']['elichens']['value']
dict1={'location':location}
dict2={'date':date}
dict3={'PM25':pm}
dict1.update(dict2)
dict1.update(dict3)
print(dict1)
```